# Given $B_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (B_i B_{n-i-1})$ and $M_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (M_i M_{n-i})$, how can I show $B_{n-1} = M_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, recurrence-relations

I have two recursions:

$$\begin{align}
B_n &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (B_i B_{n-i-1}) \\
B_1 &= 1 \\
B_0 &= 1
\end{align}$$

And:

$$\begin{align}
M_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (M_i M_{n-i}) \\
M_2 &= 1 \\
M_1 &= 1
\end{align}$$

How can I show $B_{n-1} = M_n$?

I've found:

$$\begin{align}
B_{n-1} &= \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)-1} (B_i B_{(n-1)-i-1}) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} (B_i B_{n-i-2})
\end{align}$$

Then, if I assume $M_k = B_{k-1}$ via induction, then I have:

$$\begin{align}
M_n &= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (M_k M_{n-k}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (B_{k-1} B_{n-k-1}) \\
&= \sum_{k=1-1}^{(n-1)-1} (B_{(k+1)-1} B_{(n-1)-(k+1)-1}) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (B_k B_{n-1-k})
\end{align}$$

But I am not sure if this is kosher or how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M_k=B_{k-1}$ for $k\le n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
M_{n+1}&=\sum_{i=1}^nM_iM_{n+1-i}\\
&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}M_{i+1}M_{n-i}\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}B_iB_{n-1-i}\\
&=B_n\,,
\end{align*}$$

and since $M_1=B_0$ and $M_2=B_1$, the result follows by induction. Here $(1)$ is just an index shift; if it’s not clear, let $j=i-1$, rewrite the original sum in terms of $j$, and then rename $j$ to $i$. $(2)$ uses the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I've edited my question with further work. Maybe I just don't fully understand how you end up with a `-1` in the summand instead of a `-2`. When you added a $1$ to $i$ in the summand, why did you only add it to $M_i$ and not $M_{n+1-i}$?

Comment: @gator: I changed both. Do what I suggested: let $j=i-1$, to that $i=j+1$. Then $M_i=M_{j+1}$, $M_{n+1-i}=M_{n-(i-1)}=M_j$, and as $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$, $j$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$, so you get $$\sum_{i=1}^nM_iM_{n+1-i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}M_{j+1}M_{n-j}\,.$$ Now just rename $j$ to $i$, and you have the second line of the computation. This kind of index shift is a basic manipulation; you’ll want to become fairly comfortable with it.

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying. That makes a lot more sense. When I had $n+1-i$, I came up with $n+2-i$ after index shift, when your suggestion to consider $n+1-i = n-(i-1)$ shifting to $n-i$ made it click.

Comment: @gator: Excellent! You’re welcome.